# Table using div style - width table-cell more than window size (one line / don't break line)

Tags: html, css

I need to do this  with red background in one line 
and this green  width - sum all red div.

Now, in case of more , some go to the 2nd, 3rd line etc...

I need to scroll main window horizontal, but never break line. I tried with display, float and another styles but finally I don't have idea how to do it.

Thanks

```css
/* DivTable.com */
.divTable{
    display: table;
}
.divTableRow {
    display: table-row;
}
.divTableCell, .divTableHead {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="divTable">

<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell">
    <div style="background-color: green; padding: 10px;">dd</div>
</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>

</div>
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell">
    <div style="background-color: red; width: 400px; float: left; margin-right: 5px; display: inline-block">dd</div>
    <div style="background-color: red; width: 400px; float: left; margin-right: 5px; display: inline-block">dd</div>
    <div style="background-color: red; width: 400px; float: left; margin-right: 5px; display: inline-block">dd</div>
 <div style="background-color: red; width: 400px; float: left; margin-right: 5px; display: inline-block">dd</div>
 <div style="background-color: red; width: 400px; float: left; margin-right: 5px; display: inline-block">dd</div>
    <div style="background-color: red; width: 400px; float: left; margin-right: 5px; display: inline-block">dd</div>
</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- DivTable.com -->
```

Comment: i think you should use the proper standard for creating table as defined in html using html tags for table https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: I tried to do this, but still breaks line.

Comment: Learn about overflow scroll css property

Comment: If you've solved your issue, submit it as an answer to your own question, and accept it. Updating the question to include the solution is slightly confusing, and leaves the question "unanswered".

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEM SOLVED!!**

Here is code with solution

```
table - white-space: nowrap;

div - remove float and display: inline-block
```

Thanks!

```css
/* DivTable.com */
.divTable{
    display: table;
 
}
.divTableRow {
    display: table-row;
}
.divTableCell, .divTableHead {
    display: table-cell;
}

.table {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<body>
<table class="table">

<tr>
<td>
    <div style="background-color: green; padding: 10px;">dd</div>
</div>
<td>&nbsp;</td>

</td>
<tr>
<td>
<div style="display: block;">
    <div style="background-color: red; width: 400px; margin-right: 5px; display: inline-block">dd</div>
    <div style="background-color: red; width: 400px; margin-right: 5px; display: inline-block">dd</div>
    <div style="background-color: red; width: 400px; margin-right: 5px; display: inline-block">dd</div>
 <div style="background-color: red; width: 400px; margin-right: 5px; display: inline-block">dd</div>
 <div style="background-color: red; width: 400px; margin-right: 5px; display: inline-block">dd</div>
    <div style="background-color: red; width: 400px; margin-right: 5px; display: inline-block">dd</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- DivTable.com -->
</body>
```